# Remove blank lines in CSV file with GEANY

Tags: geany

I've a file which holds empty lines, which I'd like to remove.

Is there a way to remove empty lines from `Geany`?

Note: I don't want to use another editor because I'm afraid it will add or change my csv format/encoding as I need to import these csv files as the format / encoding it is now.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist to perform it inside `geany` editor - You can use [geany lineoperations](https://plugins.geany.org/lineoperations.html) plugin which add the **Remove Empty Lines** feature to `geany`

---

A simpler way might be - to treat the file as a regular text file, and remove the empty lines using `command-line` tools (e.g. `sed`)

[Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/using-sed-to-delete-empty-lines/) You can see several examples how to remove empty line from a text file.

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/^$/d' <input-file>
```

To delete all empty lines from a file called /tmp/data.txt, enter:

```
sed '/^$/d' /tmp/data.txt
```

To store output to another file use redirection operator:

```
sed '/^$/d' /tmp/data.txt > /tmp/output.txt
```

> Note: Using `sed` to remove empty lines shouldn't change anything with the non-empty lines in file
>
> Note: In order to modify the file in place you should use `sed` `-i` flag:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' <input-file>
```

---

Example:

The original text file:

```
$ cat in.txt 
This is a test

Linux rulez


Windows sucks
Ubuntu is good server disro
```

`sed` output when running on the file:

```
$ sed  '/^$/d' in.txt 
This is a test
Linux rulez
Windows sucks
Ubuntu is good server disro
```

Comment: I tried this command sudo sed -i '/^$/d' filename.csv. it doesn't remove empty lines for me. weird.

Comment: @Zhenyu they may have whitespace in them

Comment: And if I try this command sed '/^$/d' /tmp/data.txt > /tmp/output.txt, it will just create another file with the link breaks as the old one. maybe the expression need to be changed to something else?

Comment: Lineoperations helped me :) Thanks. I couldn't make sed to work.

Comment: @Zhenyu, Maybe your CSV text is a DOS formatted text file (created by Windows). It means that there are `<carriage return><line feed>` characters at the end of each line, not only `<line feed>` as in linux text files.

Comment: @sudodus are you right, I got files from a client who's using windows... I guess that's why the expression is not working for me.

Comment: @Zhenyu, You can use `dos2unix` to convert from a DOS formatted text file. Install with `sudo apt install dos2unix` from the repository 'universe'.